# Why doesn't the ternary operator like generic types with bounded wildcards?

Tags: java, generics, ternary-operator, bounded-wildcard

The following class defines two methods, both of which intuitively have the same functionality. Each function is called with two lists of type `List<? super Integer>` and a boolean value which specifies which of those lists should be assigned to a local variable.

```
import java.util.List;

class Example {
    void chooseList1(boolean choice, List<? super Integer> list1, List<? super Integer> list2) {
        List<? super Integer> list;

        if (choice)
            list = list1;
        else
            list = list2;
    }

    void chooseList2(boolean choice, List<? super Integer> list1, List<? super Integer> list2) {
        List<? super Integer> list = choice ? list1 : list2;
    }
}
```

According to `javac 1.7.0_45`, `chooseList1` is valid while `chooseList2` is not. It complains:

```
java: incompatible types
  required: java.util.List<? super java.lang.Integer>
  found:    java.util.List<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object>
```

I know that the rules for finding the type of an expression containing the ternary operator (`… ? … : …`) are pretty complex, but as far as I understand them, it chooses the most specific type to which both the second and third arguments can be converted without an explicit cast. Here, this should be `List<? super Integer> list1` but it isn't.

I'd like to see an explanation of why this isn't the case, preferably with a reference of the *Java Language Specification* and an intuitive explanation of what could go wrong if it wasn't prevented.

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't think that's an exact duplicate, while closely related. It concerns the conditional operator as applied to inferred return types from generic method calls, where this is as applied to wildcard-capture generic types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answers applies to Java 7.

The Java Language Specification states the following about the [conditional operator (`? :`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2
>   respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing
>   conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying
>   boxing conversion to S2.
>
> The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying
>   capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).

In the expression

```
List<? super Integer> list = choice ? list1 : list2;
```

`T1` is `List<capture#1? super Integer>` and `T2` is `List<capture#2? super Integer>`. Both of these have lower bounds.

[This article](http://www.ips.tu-braunschweig.de/docs/research/goltz/JAVAG-TR-2010-02.pdf) goes into detail about how to calculate `lub(T1, T2)` (or `join function`). Let's take an example from there

```
<T> T pick(T a, T b) {
    return null;
}

<C, A extends C, B extends C> C test(A a, B b) {
    return pick(a, b); // inferred type: Object
}

void tryIt(List<? super Integer> list1, List<? super Integer> list2) {
    test(list1,  list2);
}
```

If you use an IDE and hover over `test(list1, list2)`, you will notice the return type is

```
List<? extends Object>
```

This is the best that Java's type inference can do. if `list1` was a `List<Object>` and `list2` was a `List<Number>`, the only acceptable return type is `List<? extends Object>`. Because this case has to be covered, the method must always return that type.

Similarly in

```
List<? super Integer> list = choice ? list1 : list2;
```

The `lub(T1, T2)` is again `List<? extends Object>` and its capture conversion is `List<capture#XX of ? extends Object>`.

Finally, a reference of type `List<capture#XX of ? extends Object>` can not be assigned to a variable of type `List<? super Integer>` and so the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: I have not yet understood how `lub()` of two types is calculated. But why is `List<? extends Object>` "the best that Java's type inference can do"? It would be more useful, if the result was `List<? super Integer>`, but what would be the complications, i.e. in what case would that break type safety or make something else impossible?

Comment: @Feuermurmel By declaring `? super Integer`, you declare a lower bound on the generic type. This means the actual list can be any of `List<Integer>`, `List<Number>`, `List<Object>`. The type of the `? :` expression is determined by the least upper bound of the two arguments. They are both `List<? super Integer>` but because of the lower bound, one can be a `List<Number>` and the other can be a `List<Object>`. Java cannot determine this at compile time, so the result of has to be some type that is a sub type of `Object`, ie. `List<? extends Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

Time goes by and Java changes. I am happy to inform you that since Java 8, probably due to the introduction of ["target typing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing), Feuermurmels example compiles without a problem.

The current version of the [relevant section of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3) says:

> Because reference conditional expressions can be poly expressions, they can "pass down" context to their operands.
>
> ...
>
> It also allows use of extra information to improve type checking of generic method invocations. Prior to Java SE 8, this assignment was well-typed:
>
> `List<String> ls = Arrays.asList();`
>
> but this was not:
>
> `List<String> ls = ... ? Arrays.asList() : Arrays.asList("a","b");`
>
> The rules above allow both assignments to be considered well-typed.

It's also interesting to note that the following, derived from Sotirios Delimanolis's code does not compile:

```
void tryIt(List<? super Integer> list1, List<? super Integer> list2) {
    List<? super Integer> l1 = list1 == list2 ? list1 : list2; //  Works fine
    List<? super Integer> l2 = test(list1,  list2); // Error: Type mismatch
}
```

This suggests that the information available when calculating type lower bound on the return type of `test` is different from that of the type of the conditional operator. Why this is the case I have no idea, it could be an interesting question in itself.

I use jdk_1.8.0_25.