# How to avoid an unchecked cast when using unbounded generified static functions in a ternary?

Tags: java, generics, ternary-operator

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to avoid the unchecked cast in this function (using Java 7):

```
private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlways(Always valid_orInvalid)  {
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   ValueValidator<O> vldtr = (ValueValidator<O>)(valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID
      ?  newForAlwaysValid()
      :  newForAlwaysInvalid());
   return  vldtr;
}
```

Here are the signatures of the two functions being returned:

```
private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlwaysValid()  {
private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlwaysInvalid()  {
```

(And here's the `Always` enum, which is just a boolean substitute:

```
enum Always {VALID, INVALID;};
```

)

All three functions have the same return type and contain an unbounded generic. These two questions explain why it happens, although both are about bounded generics:

- [Why doesn't the ternary operator like generic types with bounded wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065643/why-doesnt-the-ternary-operator-like-generic-types-with-bounded-wildcards)
- [Generics compilation error with ternary operator in Java 8, but not in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509488/generics-compilation-error-with-ternary-operator-in-java-8-but-not-in-java-7)

So even though this works

```
ValueValidator<Integer> intVldtr = Test.<Integer>newForAlwaysValid();
```

this doesn't:

```
private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlways(Always valid_orInvalid)  {
   return  (valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID
      ?  <O>newForAlwaysValid()
      :  <O>newForAlwaysInvalid());
}

C:\java_code\Test.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
      ?  <O>newForAlwaysValid()

...and 8 more similar errors...
```

And neither does this:

```
private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlways2(Always valid_orInvalid)  {
   return  (valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID
      ?  newForAlwaysValid()
      :  newForAlwaysInvalid());
}

C:\java_code\Test.java:15: error: incompatible types
          ?  newForAlwaysValid()
          ^
  required: ValueValidator<O>
  found:    ValueValidator<Object>
  where O is a type-variable:
    O extends Object declared in method <O>newForAlways2(Always)
```

So, to repeat the question: Is there any alternative to the unchecked cast? (I'm using Java 7.)

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
public class Test  {
   public static void main(String[] ignored)  {
      ValueValidator<Integer> intVldtr = Test.<Integer>newForAlwaysValid();
      intVldtr = Test.<Integer>newForAlways(Always.VALID);
   }
   private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlways(Always valid_orInvalid)  {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      ValueValidator<O> vldtr = (ValueValidator<O>)(valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID
         ?  newForAlwaysValid()
         :  newForAlwaysInvalid());
      return  vldtr;
   }
   private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlwaysValid()  {
      return  (new AlwaysValid<O>());
   }
   private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlwaysInvalid()  {
      return  (new AlwaysInvalid<O>());
   }
}
enum Always {VALID, INVALID;};
abstract class ValueValidator<O>  {
   public abstract boolean isValid(O to_validate);
}
class AlwaysValid<O> extends ValueValidator<O>  {
   public boolean isValid(O to_validate)  {
      return  true;
   }
}
class AlwaysInvalid<O> extends ValueValidator<O>  {
   public boolean isValid(O to_validate)  {
      return  false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the possibly dumb suggestion - but did you try specifying the type parameter of the generic method explicitly?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Do you mean like this? `(valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID ?  <Integer>newForAlwaysValid() : <Integer>newForAlwaysInvalid());`. No I didn't. But it seems moot after reading the very simple solution in the answers  :)

Comment: I see someone has already answered with the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already know that there was an issue with generic type argument inferencing with conditional operator in Java 7, which has been fixed in Java 8. Just to fix your issue, you can use explicit type argument.

Well, you already tried to do it, but that was invalid syntax. When you use explicit type argument, you always have to qualify the method invocation with either the *object type* or *class type*. So change your method to:

```
private static <O> ValueValidator<O> newForAlways(Always valid_orInvalid)  {

  ValueValidator<O> vldtr = valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID
     ?  Test.<O>newForAlwaysValid()
     :  Test.<O>newForAlwaysInvalid();
  return  vldtr;
}
```

Comment: I do believe this code works in Java 7 as well. You're very explicit about the type of each operand.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It does? I don't remember. I don't understand the second part of your comment though.

Comment: I can't believe it's that simple. Thanks to you both.

Comment: By explicitly specifying the type argument for both operands of the `?:` operator, ie. the two method invocations, the compiler will know that type of the expressions is `ValueValidator<O>` for both and there is therefore no confusion.

Comment: When you pass in a generic type into a function this way, the term is "explicit type argument"?

Comment: @aliteralmind yes, you are explicitly specifying the generic type argument. Java performs something called "type inference" when it saves you from doing this most of the time. Like Rohit said, in Java 7 it is unable to do so in this case and this has been fixed in Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do

```
ValueValidator<O> vldtr = valid_orInvalid == Always.VALID 
            ? Test.<O>newForAlwaysValid()
            : Test.<O>newForAlwaysInvalid();
```