# Does Java explicitly disallow me to call a function ternary operator with multiple return type possibilities?

Tags: java

As demonstrated below, I have two functions who's arg types differ (String,int).
I now have a third function

```
public void foo(String bar){}
public void foo(int bar){}
public boolean cond(){ return Math.random() > 0.5 ? true : false; }

public void runsBad(){
  String str = "";
  int i = 0;
  foo( cond() ? str : i );
}

public void runsGood(){
  if( cond() )
    foo( str );
  else
    foo( i );
}
```

`runsGood` runs without problems. However, `runsBad` returns the following error:

```
|  Error:
|  no suitable method found for foo(cond() ? str : i)
|      method foo(int) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; bad type in conditional expression
|            java.lang.String cannot be converted to int)
|      method foo(java.lang.String) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; bad type in conditional expression
|            int cannot be converted to java.lang.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or can Java simply not handle the ternary operator as demonstrated?

Comment: Yes, that is not allowed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967819/java-conditional-operator-and-different-types/24967937

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation of how the ternary expression works is incorrect. It's an expression. It's first evaluated, and the result is then passed as argument to `foo()`.

So, instead of

```
if( cond() )
    foo( str );
else
    foo( i );
```

It's actually equivalent to

```
SomeCommonSuperTypeOfStringAndInt value = cond() ? str : i;
foo(value);
```

So this would only compile if there was a `foo()`method accepting a Serializable or an Object as argument.

Answer (score 1):

The type of expression `cond() ? str : i` is neither String nor int. When you call foo with this parameter, Java tries to cast it to String (so it tries to cast i to String), but it fails. Then it tries to cast it to int (so it tries to cast str to int), but also fails. So Java can't find a method with required signature and throws an exception.